# Get Method Call arguments in flutter window

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

Does anyone know how to get an argument pass by MethodChannel in windows?
Here is my code to send and receive data.
I need to get data value in string type

```
String data = "Some data";
await platform.invokeMethod("OpenViewer", {"data":data});
```

```
channel->SetMethodCallHandler([](const flutter::MethodCall<>& call, std::unique_ptr<flutter::MethodResult<>> result)
        {
            // check method name called from dart
            if (call.method_name().compare("OpenViewer") == 0) {
                
            }
            else {
                result->NotImplemented();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use something like below

```
 if (method_call.method_name().compare("launch") == 0) {
    std::string url = GetUrlArgument(method_call);
    if (url.empty()) {
      result->Error("argument_error", "No URL provided");
      return;
    }

    std::optional<std::string> error = LaunchUrl(url);
    if (error) {
      result->Error("open_error", error.value());
      return;
    }
    result->Success(EncodableValue(true));
```

For more read [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher_windows/windows/url_launcher_plugin.cpp) from url_launcher

Comment: Thank you, i had to merge and split strings to send parameters every time :D